# How to get the request and response information and send them as a post request in Jersey?

Tags: java, api, design-patterns, jersey, jax-rs

For example, when a user calls GET /API1/employee to get all the information about the employees in the database. I want to create a class and implement serval methods to get the request and response information like userid, timestamp when the api is called. And then send the JSON data to another api as a post request? Any reference or example about it?

Comment: Look at this example https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples/flight-mgmt-webapp

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: I try to use @Consumes to get the request body. But it will change the original code. Should I use something like filters and Interceptors? I am new to the rest web service.